# Unable to use ediff with emacs and evil due to window configuration

Tags: evil, window, window-splitting, ediff

Running emacs 25.2.2 with evil installed and updated from Melpa.

When I run ediff, it asks for usual buffer A and buffer B and then ONLY the ediff buffer in its own frame is visible with 'Type ? for help'. I can switch to the other emacs frame where the two files are  shown as expected. But none of the ediff commands work.

Earlier (without evil) ediff showed a nice three window setup with two buffers on top and ediff control buffer at the bottom.

How do I get that behavior back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ediff-window-setup-function` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Select "Single Frame".

(Much better than the default, IMHO; especially in a tiling window manager, where the multi-frame config is all but unusable.)

---

I can't fathom why `evil` might be poking its nose into that configuration, mind you.  If that *actually* turns out to be the cause, I would report it as a bug.  Note that the multi-frame config *is* the default for GUI frames, though; so maybe it's the other way around, and something which *used* to set the single-window config is now refraining from doing so.

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect. I am using KDE Plasma. But single frame is much better than the default, I agree. And no, even with `evil` `ediff` now behaves as expected. So I guess it was about setting that option :)